# Enable client validation Yii

Tags: php, forms, validation, yii

I have some questions about Yii client validation. When I assign `clientOptions -> validateOnSubmit` to true, Yii automatically validates my form on the client side? Ok, so the validation rules will get rules from `rules()` method in model? And why when I write `'minlength' => 2` directly into field definition in form template it won't work?

Comment: `validateOnSubmit` does not have anything to do with client-side (javascript) validation. `validateOnSubmit` causes an AJAX request to be sent to the backend and it will validate your model and your form won't submit if that validation fails. [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#clientOptions-detail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sample of CActiveForm widget:

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                            'id' => 'register-form',
                            'enableClientValidation' => true,
                            'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
                            'clientOptions' => array(
                                'validateOnSubmit' => true,
                                'validateOnChange' => false,
                                'validateOnType' => false,
                                'errorCssClass' => 'has-error',
                                'successCssClass' => 'has-success',
                                'afterValidate' => 'js:function(form, data, hasError){}'
                        )));
```

The `enableClientValidation` activate jquery based validation on your page. and client options specify how client validation works. Yes, validation rule come from `rule()` function in the model, so you should define ANY validation rule there.